# ASP.NET default regular expression for users' passwords

Tags: asp.net, regex, passwords, createuserwizard

What is the default regular expression used by asp.net create user wizard?

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.passwordregularexpression.aspx), it should be something like this:

**Regular Expression**: `@\"(?:.{7,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})`

**Validation Message**: Your password must be 7 characters long, and contain at least one number and one special character.

However, it does not work as it does not accept something like *3edc£edc*, which is actually accepted when using the default create user wizard.

Any idea about how can I get this regular expression?

Comment: you can search a regular expression according to your requirement on this URL :
http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password

Comment: @GauravAgrawal although I appreciate your answer, it is not what I am looking for. My question was very specific: "What is the default regular expression used by asp.net create user wizard?". As you can see, there is no way I can find that out through the link that you provided. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order

```
^(?=(.*\d))(?=(.*\W)).{7,}
```

I additionally removed the `{1,}` and anchored it to the start of the string and you don't need a group around the last part

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30a8v)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `?:` in `(?:.{7,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})` that is "consuming" the fist seven characters or more characters. It should be `?=` OR you can invert the order: `(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})(?:.{7,})`